# Как сгенерить скрипт от react для интеграции в другие сайты

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Как сгенерить скрипт от react для интеграции в другие сайты например(php). Пробовал через npm run build, но что если на другом сайте пересоберут проект, то моя папка build сотрётся. Подскажите может есть ли какие-то библиотеки ?

Comment: Не очень понял, папка `build` и так должна переписываться при каждой новой сборке. А как собрать не очень важно, кто-то может сборку покрыть полифилами, кто-то оставить просто минифицированную версию js. Вас не должно это волновать, если я, конечно, понял из-за чего вы беспокоитесь

Comment: Спасибо, да немного вопрос не так звучит